# Merge different object types in Java 7

Tags: java, hashmap, java-7

I have an object, trailer, that looks like this:

```
{
    "assetId": 0,
    "type": "VN",
    "number": "69492",
    "customerId": "DTMO",
    "yardId": 0,
    "latitude": 36.994444444444444444444444,
    "longitude": -88.483611111111111111111111,
    "id": 0
}
```

And I have an object that returns a list of Customers:

```
{
    "customerId": "DTMX",
    "yardId": 1,
},
{
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "yardId": 2,
},
{
    "customerId": "GHR",
    "yardId": 3,
}
```

I need to set the yardId in the first object where the customerId matches in the second object.  I'm trying to use a HashMap but it seems to only work when both objects are of the same type.

**EDITED**

```
HashMap<String, Trailer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Trailer t : trailersAS400) {
    map.put(t.getNumber(), t);
}
for (Trailer t : trailersSQLServer) {
    String key = t.getNumber();
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) { 
        map.put(key, t);
    }
}

trailers = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

for (Trailer t : trailers) {
    String key = t.getNumber();
    Trailer trailerToModify = map.remove(key);              
    trailerToModify.setYardId(99);
    map.put(key, trailerToModify);
}

trailers = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

I need to put the actual yardId in place of the 99.  I'm just learning about maps in Java.

**EDIT 2**

No errors, it runs, but still not getting a value for the yardId.

```
HashMap<String, Trailer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Trailer t : trailersAS400) {
    map.put(t.getNumber(), t);
}
for (Trailer t : trailersSQLServer) {
    String key = t.getNumber();
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) { 
        map.put(key, t);
    }
}

HashMap<String, Integer> mapCustomers = new HashMap<>();
for (Customer c : customers) {
    mapCustomers.put(c.getCustomerId(), c.getYardId());
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Trailer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer yardId = mapCustomers.get(entry.getKey());
    yardId = yardId == null ? entry.getValue().getYardId() : yardId;
    entry.getValue().setYardId(yardId);
}

trailers = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: Can you give the code of both classes ?

Answer (score 0):

In your map, you are trying to replace a Trailer with a Customer. The map won't let you do that; that's part of its design. Essentially, the compiler is telling you that you need to rethink what you are doing.

Your real problem is that you have thought through what you are trying to do. You want to update each Trailer's yardId based on its Customer.

To do that, you need a Map. As you loop through your Trailer's, look up the Customer for that trailer. Use the yardId from the Customer to update the Trailer's yardId.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is :

- iterate on the `Trailers`
- if the `customerId` is present in one of the `Customer` of the `List`, then you can modify with its `yardId`

```
// What you have
Map<String, Trailer> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

// Create a map : customerId/yardId
Map<String, Integer> mapCustomers = customers.stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getCustomerId,    
                                                                       Customer::getYardId));

// Iterate on the Trailers
for (Map.Entry<String, Trailer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // get the yardId related to the customerId if present OR take the actuel yardId
    int yardId = mapCustomers.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getYardId());

    // set the value to the trailer
    entry.getValue().setYardId(yardId);
}
```

---

Condensed code is :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Trailer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    entry.getValue().setYargId(mapCustomers.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getYargId()));
}
```

---

**JAVA 7** will look like

```
Map<String, Integer> mapCustomers = new HashMap<>();

for (Customer c : customers) {
    mapCustomers.put(c.getCustomerId(), c.getYardId());
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Trailer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer yardId = mapCustomers.get(entry.getKey());
    yardId = yardId == null ? entry.getValue().getYardId() : yardId;
    entry.getValue().setYardId(yardId);
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java 8.  We're still on Java 7.

Comment: This looks so close but I'm getting 0 for all the yardIds.  See Edit 2 above.